# AWS Cognito - how to create user record in dynamodb after a user confirms registration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a user record in ddb for cognito users once they confirm their registration. I wish to use the (federated) identity id of the user as the primary key.

However, the identity id is not available in the postConfirmation lambda trigger. In fact, the identity id is not available until the user authenticates with their access token. I guess this makes sense given that cognito user pools are a provider, like facebook and google. You wouldn't create an identity until they login with that provider.

Unlike facebook and google, there is no oauth callback to hit to create a record when signing into a cognito user pool. The user just signs in like so:

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: self.IdentityPoolId,
            Logins: {
              [`cognito-idp.${self.region}.amazonaws.com/${self.poolData.UserPoolId}`]: result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
            }
        });
        console.log("AuthService: set the AWS credentials - " + JSON.stringify(AWS.config.credentials));
        self.currentUser = cognitoUser;
        cb(null, result);
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      cb(err, null);
    }

});
```

Only then is the identity id created. What is then the standard way to implement creating a user record? Is it standard to create the record when the user first signs in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways you could do this, I think. One might be to use the sub value as the key instead of the identity id. It's given to a user on creation, and is globally unique (like identity id). If you go this route, your thought about using the postConfirmation callback is great.

If you really want identity id (which you might if you have other AWS resources to access and want to access them), then I might just recommend building your own hook into the onSuccess block there. Check if a row for that identity id exists, and do nothing if so. If not, create it. Does that make sense for your use case? Or are there more wrinkles?

Comment: My use case would be to have an api gateway endpoint like /users/:id/projects that fetches all the projects for a user. Would it be easier to use the sub value or the identity id? I was thinking the identity id.

Comment: User pools has tight integration with API GW. If you're mapping everything behind API GW, you could use sub instead. Using identity id instead would work better if you wanted to get access to things like Dynamo directly from the client. I think the work is pretty similar in either case.

Comment: By globally unique, do you mean subs are unique across all your user pools?